# How to make html page scroll to top most at each refresh?

Tags: html, css

I have a big page therefore I cannot paste the whole code here. But the problem is clear and briefly like this: There are animations on the page. On every page refresh, visible area scrolls a bit down. The framework I use is react js. I used below code but it doesn't scroll to top most, it leaves a little space. And on each page refresh the gap increases.

```
useEffect(()=>{
        window.scrollTo({top: 0, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth' }) 
      }, [])
```

Only hard refreshing the page starts without any gap. Is there a different way to have a try? Any help?

Comment: You don't have to put all your code into the question, but you should be able to create an example - using elements with large heights perhaps, which will make it much easier to help. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks, I will try to ask questions following the rules